What is proper way to set size for the fixed size image with getImageProps()?
I need help to properly understand how to set image sizes with getImageProps(). I have the following situation: 3 images (mobile, tablet, desktop) must be shown depending on media size. A classic use case of Art Direction. I have the following:
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/alt-text */
import mobileImage from "@/assets/images/image-profile-mobile.webp";
import tabletImage from "@/assets/images/image-profile-tablet.webp";
import desktopImage from "@/assets/images/image-profile-desktop.webp";
import { getImageProps } from "next/image";

export default 
function
 Home() {
  
const
 common = { alt: "Profile picture" };
  
const
 {
    props: { srcSet: desktop },
  } = getImageProps({
    ...common,
    width: desktopImage.width,
    height: desktopImage.height,
    quality: 80,
    src: "/images/image-profile-desktop.webp",
  });
  
const
 {
    props: { srcSet: tablet },
  } = getImageProps({
    ...common,
    width: tabletImage.width,
    height: tabletImage.height,
    quality: 70,
    src: "/images/image-profile-tablet.webp",
  });
  
const
 {
    props: { srcSet: mobile, ...rest },
  } = getImageProps({
    ...common,
    width: mobileImage.width,
    height: mobileImage.height,
    quality: 70,
    src: "/images/image-profile-mobile.webp",
  });

  return (
    <main>
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcSet={desktop} />
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcSet={tablet} />
        <source media="(min-width: 640px)" srcSet={mobile} />
        <img {...rest} className="h-auto w-[174px] md:w-[350px] lg:w-[445px]" />
      </picture>
    </main>
  );
}


Next.js produces the following sourceSets for the images:
{
  desktop: '/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-desktop.webp&w=1080&q=80 1x,
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-desktop.webp&w=1920&q=80 2x'
}
{
  tablet: '/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-tablet.webp&w=750&q=70 1x,
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-tablet.webp&w=1920&q=70 2x'
}
{
  mobile: '/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=384&q=70 1x,
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=750&q=70 2x'
}

Images are rendered to half their intrinsic size. For example, a mobile image that is 348px wide is rendered to 174px wide. The sizes are set with CSS. Both variants of each image are identical, so a 1x image is precisely the same as a 2x image. I tried switching the browser's pixel density setting, and it didn't make any difference.
When I try setting the sizes property on any of those images, it throws the source set into this verbose mode. For example, if I set sizes on mobile to sizes: "175px" (and I tried 175w as well with the same result), The outcome seems to be the default list of sizes (which technically all are serving precisely the same image):
{ 
mobile: '
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=16&q=70 16w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=32&q=70 32w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=48&q=70 48w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=64&q=70 64w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=96&q=70 96w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=128&q=70 128w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=256&q=70 256w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=384&q=70 384w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=640&q=70 640w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=750&q=70 750w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=828&q=70 828w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=1080&q=70 1080w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=1200&q=70 1200w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=1920&q=70 1920w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=2048&q=70 2048w, 
/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fimage-profile-mobile.webp&w=3840&q=70 3840w'
}

The question is, why are these strange 1x and 2x values? If the mobile image is rendered to 174px wide, the 1x should be 174px wide, and the 2x should be 348px. Why is there no size difference between 1x and 2x? What is the best approach with an Art Direction setup with several fixed-size images?
Thank you!
